# Too many file descriptors while capturing stdout

Tags: linux, macos, go, file-descriptor

I have thousands of tests in my Go project, and to ensure correct output from the CLI, I wrote a function to capture stdout:

```golang
// captureStdout captures everything written to the terminal and returns it as a string.
func captureStdout(f func(w io.Writer)) string {
    originalStdout := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    f(w)

    _ = w.Close()
    out, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    os.Stdout = originalStdout
    _ = r.Close()

    return string(out)
}
// No error handling for smaller code snippet
```

This function works fine, but when I run it a couple of thousand times, it fails randomly.

I figured out, it has to do with the file descriptor limit on Linux, which is 1024.

> Linux systems limit the number of file descriptors that any one process may open to 1024 per process. (This condition is not a problem on Solaris machines, x86, x64, or SPARC). After the directory server has exceeded the file descriptor limit of 1024 per process, any new process and worker threads will be blocked. - [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19476-01/821-0505/file-descriptor-requirements.html#:%7E:text=Linux%20systems%20limit%20the%20number,worker%20threads%20will%20be%20blocked.)

On Windows, the tests work flawlessly.

How would I go around this limit in Go for Linux machines?

Comment: "How would I go around this limit ...?", you set the ulimit, but that is an XY question, figure out why you are running out of FDs in the first place. Are you trying to run this a couple thousand times concurrently? You have blocking reads and writes, are you certain you are not leaving this entire function blocked in tests and failing to close the pipes?

Comment: The function is not called concurrently. I think with the r.Close() and w.Close() the pipe is closed properly?

Comment: `f(w)` (which I assume is writing something) can block if there are no readers, and you don't read until after that function returns. In general you have to read concurrently if you are replacing stdout with a pipe. Are you certain these calls are returning properly?

Comment: Given that `f` takes an `io.Writer` argument, can you avoid all use of file descriptors with `var buf bytes.Buffer; f(&buf); return buf.String()`?

Comment: Debugging leaking FD can be hard, a good starting point is to [trace](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace) your program, the output can be inspected with `go tool trace` and show you exactly what is going on. Also, on linux you can inspect the open file descriptors of running process by listing the `/proc/{pid}/fd` directory, though you can only do this you can get the PID of the running tests and list the dir before the tests are done. So you might need to add some delays in your tests if you are going that route

Comment: to add to caveman's comment : from within the process itself, you can use `/proc/self` ; for example : open `/proc/self/fd` and list the elements in that directory.

Comment: playground : https://play.golang.org/p/p6c1107dgv4

Comment: The function you supply works as stated, but i can't reproduce this issue with, say, https://github.com/farrellit/stackoverflow/tree/main/69831267

Comment: @MarvinJWendt : the elements in your current question are not enough to help diagnose the problem. Can you please add extra elements, such as how the tests are run (inside a single `go test ...` run, or accross several processes), or what kind of actions your `f (w io.Writer)` functions can do ?

Answer (score 0):

Having not enough file descriptors is most often caused by a file descriptor leak. For example forgetting to call .Close on opened files or network sockets after they are no longer needed.

If you want to open more than 1024 files/network connections at the same time, on purpose. You can increase this limit using the `ulimit` command(and the proper flags). This command will increase the limit for your current shell session, which seems appropriate if it is regarding unit tests.

Comment: Hi, sadly the ulimit workaround does not work for me. I set it to a million and it still crashes. Does the temporary ulimit also work when running Go tests? Or do the Go tests fetch the actual ulimit?

Comment: When changing the limit you have to change both the soft and hard limit. The go test process should inherit the setting since it is a child process of the shell. You can inspect the current limits with the `ulimit -a` to make sure they actually changed (`ulimit -a -H` to view the hard limits)